# Google app engine java with cassandra modify thread group error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cassandra, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am having a problem with CassandraDB in Google web applications

I've been using Eclipse (java EE IDE), installed all google plugins in it, and developed a sample google web application. It has been deployed to the web, and it's working correctly.

Now I want to use my CassandraDB. Here I am using Cassandra API to connect with database. All required jar files are placed in lib directory which is in WEB-INF folder and also added to the classpath. However, when I run my application it gives me a java.security.AccessControlException:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tPAL.png
```

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this Exception?

Answer (score 1):

GAE is [very restrictive](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox) when it comes to multi-threading capabilities. The driver won't be allowed to manage its own thread-pool for connection handling. I'm not aware of any GAE compatible driver. On the other hand its probably not a good idead anyway to use your own Cassandra instance instead of the GAE datastore due to security, performance and availability implications.

Answer (score 0):

As Stefan mentioned, GAE is very restrictive for multi-threading activities. Hence, standard environment of GAE cannot be used for accessing Cassandra database. But you can use Cassandra database on GAE in its [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). As of now, flexible environment is in Beta version and is not recommended for production use.